# How to go full screen with VideoPlayer() in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm using the following code in my project and it works great.

But I need to know if its possible to play the video in full screen when the user taps on a button or any other action.

This is my code:

```
VideoPlayer(player: AVPlayer(url:  URL(string: "https://xxx.mp4")!)) {
    VStack {
        Text("Watermark")
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .background(Color.white.opacity(0.7))
        Spacer()
    }
            .frame(width: 400, height: 300)
}
.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 300)
```

So basically, the idea is to make the `VideoPlayer` to go full screen similar to youtube's video player.

Is this possible using the `VideoPlayer()` in `swiftUI`?

Comment: Is there a green button on the top left corner of the window?

Comment: @apodidae, no there isn't any buttons at the top left. only 1 button on the top right to mute/unmute the video.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They should include an option or have that button by default in `VideoPlayer` I don't know why apple did this if someone knows add a comment about the same, anyways

There is a simpler method though

```swift
struct CustomVideoPlayer: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
  
  func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> AVPlayerViewController {
    let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
    let url: String = "https://xxx.mp4"
    let player1 = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: url)!)
    
    controller.player = player1
    return controller
  }
  
  func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: AVPlayerViewController, context: Context) {
    
  }
}
```

Try this code and call `CustomVideoPlayer()` and give it a `frame` with any height and you will have a fullscreen option on the top left corner just like youtube

EDIT: I tried the accepted solution but I don't think it is going fullscreen

Comment: It's a great solution but not perfect. Unfortunately when you enter fullscreen it triggers the .onDisappear of your CustomVideoPlayer and its parents. I guess that's why Apple did not add the feature to swiftUI VideoPlayer.

Comment: I was able to work around this issue. It's all documented in the README of my AZVideoPlayer package:  https://github.com/adamzarn/AZVideoPlayer

Answer (score 4):

Actually, you can create a @State property to determine if to show it as fullscreen or as embedded. Here's a full example:

```swift
import AVKit
import SwiftUI

struct MyView: View {
    // MARK: Lifecycle

    init(url: URL) {
        self.player = AVPlayer(url: url)
    }

    // MARK: Internal

    let player: AVPlayer

    @State var showFullscreen = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            videoView
                .frame(height: 300)
        }.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showFullscreen) {
            videoView
        }
    }

    // MARK: Private

    @ViewBuilder
    private var videoView: some View {
        VideoPlayer(player: player) {
            if !showFullscreen {
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "arrow.up.left.and.arrow.down.right")
                            .padding(16)
                            .foregroundStyle(.white)
                            .tint(.white)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                showFullscreen.toggle()
                            }

                        Spacer()
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You will end up with a button on top right screen to toggle between fullscreen.

[image: player no controls]

It is not 100% since it's always there and when the controls are displayed it will dim a bit but beside that it works just fine.

[image: player with controls]

Answer (score 2):

I took @Viraj D's answer and created a Swift package called [AZVideoPlayer](https://github.com/adamzarn/AZVideoPlayer). Add the package with SPM or feel free to just copy the source code into your project.

The package also adds the following:

1. Addresses the issue where `onDisappear` is called when full screen presentation begins by allowing a way to ignore the call in that particular case.
2. Allows you to have the video continue playing when ending full screen presentation (it pauses by default).

Here's an example:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import AVKit
import AZVideoPlayer

struct ContentView: View {
    var player: AVPlayer?
    @State var willBeginFullScreenPresentation: Bool = false
    
    init(url: URL) {
        self.player = AVPlayer(url: url)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        AZVideoPlayer(player: player,
                      willBeginFullScreenPresentationWithAnimationCoordinator: willBeginFullScreen,
                      willEndFullScreenPresentationWithAnimationCoordinator: willEndFullScreen)
        .onDisappear {
            // onDisappear is called when full screen presentation begins, but the view is
            // not actually disappearing in this case so we don't want to reset the player
            guard !willBeginFullScreenPresentation else {
                willBeginFullScreenPresentation = false
                return
            }
            player?.pause()
            player?.seek(to: .zero)
        }
    }
    
    func willBeginFullScreen(_ playerViewController: AVPlayerViewController,
                             _ coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        willBeginFullScreenPresentation = true
    }
    
    func willEndFullScreen(_ playerViewController: AVPlayerViewController,
                           _ coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        // This is a static helper method provided by AZVideoPlayer to keep
        // the video playing if it was playing when full screen presentation ended
        AZVideoPlayer.continuePlayingIfPlaying(player, coordinator)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's how I managed to do it. I hope this helps someone else in the future.

This is a rough idea but it works as it was intended to.

Basically, I've put the VideoPlayer in a VStack and gave it a full width and height.

I gave the VStack a set height and full width.

I gave the VStack a tapGesture and changed its width and height on double tap and this way, all its content (VideoPlayer) will resize accordingly.

**This is the code:**

```
struct vidPlayerView: View {
    
    @State var animate = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack{
  
            VideoPlayer(player: AVPlayer(url:  URL(string: "https://xxxx.mp4")!)) {
                VStack {
                    Image(systemName: "info.circle")
                        .font(.system(size: 18, weight: .bold))
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                    Spacer()
                }
                .frame(width: 400, height: 300, alignment: .topLeading)
            }
          
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .topLeading)
            
            Spacer()
            
        }.onTapGesture(count: 2) {
            withAnimation {
                                self.animate.toggle()
                            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: self.animate ? .infinity : UIScreen.main.bounds.width, maxHeight: self.animate ? .infinity : 300, alignment: .topLeading)
        
        

        
    }
}
```

The above code can be executed by taping on a button or any other actions.