# Swiftui video player no full screen option?

Tags: swift, fullscreen

I am trying to play a video with a given url in my app.
I tried to use VideoPlayer(), but there is one thing missing, that's the full screen option. I don't know how can support it with an full screen button.

[No full screen button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HShwv.png)

```
 VideoPlayer(
      player: player
 )
    .aspectRatio(16/9, contentMode: .fit)
    .onAppear {
         player.allowsExternalPlayback = true
         player.play()
     }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to go full screen with VideoPlayer() in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67824702/how-to-go-full-screen-with-videoplayer-in-swiftui)